# Detect if MATLAB startup.m is running on a worker

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

A colleague has a MATLAB `startup.m` file that contains interactive code (it calls the command `questdlg` to ask him which project directory he wishes to work in).

This works fine for him when running MATLAB directly. However, he also needs to run MATLAB code in parallel, having started up a `matlabpool`.

When starting up, the workers in the `matlabpool` are running his `startup.m` file, getting to the `questdlg` and then hanging (infinitely, or until <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>).

An easy solution is to just get rid of the interactive code from his `startup.m`, as it's not really essential.

But is there a way to detect whether this `startup.m` is being run by a worker starting up - something similar to `isdeployed` or `ismcc`? Then he could keep the interactive code that he finds useful, but only execute it when not starting up a worker.

The command `getCurrentWorker` seemed like it might be what was needed, but I believe that only works during the execution of a task, rather than at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `usejava` function to see if the interactive desktop is running, which is probably a good enough approximation unless you frequently use `-nodesktop` mode.

```
if usejava('desktop')
    questdlg(...);
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Edric. Personally, I would be fine with something undocumented if it was the "right" way of doing it - but something documented that basically works is fine here too. Sounds like `usejava` will work - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`labindex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labindex.html) and, failing that, `labSend` and `labReceive`.

Comment: Unfortunately this will tell you nothing as those are set up (or not) much later than `startup.m`

Comment: @JoshuaBarr Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'd also tried `labindex`, which doesn't work for the reason @Edric mentions. @Edric, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @SamRoberts - yes, there are ways and means as I'm sure you realise - it's a question of how undocumented you wish to go. I'll post an answer that ought to help.

Answer (score 0):

At  least for my R2014b,

```
   isempty(getCurrentWorker)
```

seem to do the job:

```
>> getCurrentWorker
ans =
     []
>> parfor i=1:2;disp(getCurrentWorker);end
 Worker
                 Host: IMP.OIMRDS
         ComputerType: WIN64

            ProcessId: 15784
 Worker
                 Host: IMP.OIMRDS
         ComputerType: WIN64

            ProcessId: 17220
```